# Layout below layout programatically inside Relative View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to programatically add two views as children of a root `RelativeLayout`, when one view is below another.

Here's the root view (which also resides in another `CoordinatorLayout`, but I don't think it's related):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Now, here is one of the two layouts I'm trying to add programatically:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView    
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

and the other one:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_group_members"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/members_title"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I added this with this code:

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(topView);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bottomView.getId());
bottomView.setLayoutParams(lp);
container.addView(bottomView);
```

The result is: the bottom view is not visible.

What I tried:

1. Changing the first `RecyclerView`'s height to `WRAP_CONTENT` (thought it might fill all space and hide the bottom layout), which had no effect.
2. Instead of setting the `LayoutParams` to the bottom view, to:

   ```
   container.addView(bottomView, lp);
   ```

But it didn't work either.

3. Using a `LinearLayout` instead of the `RelativeLayout` container, same behaviour either.

I have no more ideas what can cause this problem, and by looking at similar questions, nothing worked. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why ALL askers are using setLayoutParams when you have right there the call to addView where its supposed to pass the layoutparams as 2º parameter...

Comment: You know, when one thing doesn't work you're trying the other.
I was not sure what's the difference (I assumed there is), and I mentioned I tried everything. Don't you try everything you know before you go ask someone else?

Answer (score 0):

Your first view is RecyclerView, which is a scrollable view. It doesn't matter if you set the height wrap_content to RecyclerView/ListView. In all cases, it's going to fill the whole screen unless you set a specific height to the RecyclerView, obviously smaller than the device's height. The second view below RecyclerView would show up then. Here's what you can try:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, HEIGHT_OF_VIEW);
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Well I can't know what's the size of the recycler view ahead, since only in runtime the adapter items are instansiated. Unless I programatically set, ahead, the size of the adapter items... but that feels wrong

Answer (score 0):

The LinearLayout approach should work.

Just mind that:
1) Container LinearLayout should have layout_height MATCH_PARENT
2) RecyclerView should have layout_height of 0 and layout_weight of 1

If instead you want to keep the RelativeLayout approach try:
1) BottomLayout with rule RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM
2) RecyclerView with rule RelativeLayout.ABOVE

Example 2nd approach:

```
RelativeLayout containerLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

RelativeLayout bottomLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
bottomLayout.setId(R.id.bottom_id);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bottomLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            bottomLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
bottomLayout.setLayoutParams(bottomLayoutParams);
bottomLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
TextView bottomTextView = new TextView(this);
bottomTextView.setText("Bottom Layout");
bottomLayout.addView(bottomTextView);
containerLayout.addView(bottomLayout);

RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.bottom_id);
recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
containerLayout.addView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: First approach result is only bottom view is visible.
Second approach results in both views visible & overlapping...

Comment: I added an example of the RelativeLayout approach you asked me

Comment: I guess that doesn't work since I'm inside a CoordinatorLayout (basically I have a flexible space and an image on top of it. Tried to add additional text on the image, but it didn't work)